# How do I fix a CrossScopeAccessNotAllowedException in ServiceNow?

Tags: servicenow

I am trying to get my instance url via script in a scoped application. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
com.glide.script.fencing.CrossScopeAccessNotAllowedException: Access to Glide API: properties from scope x_pnnla_siteaccess not allowed
Caused by error in <refname> at line 1

==> 1: var url = gs.getProperty('glide.servlet.uri');
2: gs.info(url);
```

How do I access the allow the property access from a scoped application?

Answer (score -2):

Simply put, you don't.
You should not access sys_properties from another scope in your scoped application.

So copy the property into your own scope and access this one.

You can read more about this here: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/newyork-application-development/page/build/applications/concept/c_ApplicationScope.html

Comment: Manually creating the property in the custom scope is not maintainable. If the instance URL changes each custom property would have to be updated.